# $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ not order isomorphic to $\mathbb R$

Tags: order-theory

I am trying to show that if you use the lexicographic ordering induced by $\mathbb R$ on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ they are not isomorphic.

Is it enough to use the counter-example that whilst $(1,0) < (1,1)$ in $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$, $1$ is not strictly less than $1$ in $\mathbb R$?

Thanks

Comment: No.  You actually need to show that there's *no* order-preserving bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$.  Not just that a particular one doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the fundamental property of the order on the reals is that every subset that has an upper bound has a lowest upper bound.

Is this property shared by the product under the lexicographic order?

Your example is not a proof: it's obvious that an order preserving bijection must have strange properties, if it existed.

Comment: My attempt at proving that ℝ×ℝ does not have the least upper bound property:  Choose subset A = {(a,b): a,b in ℝ, a<0}.  Let w = (c,d) be the least upper bound.  If c>0 then (0,d) is an upper bound for A less than w. Contradiction.  If c<0 then (c/2,d) is in A so w is not an upper bound.  So c=0 and w is of the form (0,d). But (0,d-1) is an upper bound less than w. Contradiction.  So A does not have a least upper bound.

Comment: @M.Hope I'd say it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

No: that merely shows that certain attempts to build an isomorphism can’t work. You need to show that no map from $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, no matter how weird, is an order-isomorphism.

HINT: For $x\in\Bbb R$ let $I_x=\{x\}\times(0,1)$; this is an open interval in $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$. $\{I_x:x\in\Bbb R\}$ is therefore an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint open intervals in $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$. Does such a family exist in $\Bbb R$? Remember, ever non-empty open interval in $\Bbb R$ contains a rational.